# formatting integer into string numbers in jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a number such as 50000 in the following variable:

```
var i = 50000
```

and I want to format it as a string such that it prints out 50.000,00 . What is the easiest way in jQuery to do this aside from using a plugin, such as the numbers plugin.

Comment: If you don't want to use any plugin - why did you mention jquery?

Comment: Is the number guaranteed to be an Integer?

Comment: @zerkms I mean using built in jQuery function, nothing else

Comment: @adit: have you checked http://api.jquery.com/ for available functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809136/how-to-format-numbers-with-white-spaces-between-thousands/10809178#10809178

Comment: @HMR yes number is always an integer. It can be 2 digit 3 digit, etc..

Comment: Then Derek has already answered the question using a regexp. From his answer with a slight change: `console.log(value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")+",00");`

Answer (score 5):

```
var value = 50000.69,
    formatted = value.toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

console.log(formatted);
```

Native JavaScript, and you don't even need jQuery or any plugin. Very flexible as you can modify the regex however you want.

---

As [HMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357099/formatting-integer-into-string-numbers-in-jquery/17357147?noredirect=1#comment25187432_17357147) mentioned, use the following code for your specified format:

```
formatted = value.replace(".",",").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
```

Add `.toFixed(`**`2`**`)` if you want a maximum of 2 digits after the decimal point, but I'm sure you get it. ;)

Comment: You got it slightly worng; dot is the thousand seporator and comma is the decimal seporator you could do: formatted = `value.toFixed(2).replace(".",",").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");`

Comment: @HMR - Not used to using `.` as the thousand separator :P And thanks for the suggestion for using `toFixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the JS version of the PHP function `number_format`, by the PHP.js project:
http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/

```
number_format(50000, 2, ',', '.');
```

It's very flexible, if that's something you're going to need.

Another way is to use or base yourself in the [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string/blob/c8cd7fdb230a8522be5aa5fb7d3e32445bf79aaf/lib/underscore.string.js#L454) approach, which actually looks like PHP.js's one.